# Fastest algorithm to compare two collections or list

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I need the fastest algorithm in .NET C# to compare two large collections (200000 records in each collection). I need to validate each row of collection 1 with each row of collection 2 and return the row of collection 1 which has duplicate records in collection 2.

Please suggest a linq query or lookup table which ever is faster..The records are like A2368FG,AD5686,B678SD,C68AGFD,...

```
    private bool CheckValidCode(string stdCode, List<COde> CodeMap, out int count)
        {
            bool bRetVal = true;
            count = 1;
                try
                {

              List<COde> tempCodeMap = new List<COde>();

              for (int i = 0; i < CodeMap.Count; i++)
              {
                  if (CodeMap[i].StandardCode == (stdCode))
                  {
                      tempCodeMap .Add(customerCodeMappings[i]);
                      if (CodeMap[i + 1].StandardCode == (stdCode))
                      {
                          tempCodeMap .Add(CodeMap[i + 1]);
                      }
                      break;
                  }
              }
    return tempCodeMap ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Are they simple string objects in each?  If so, you can use something like

```
Collection1.Intersect(collection2)
```

Which will return all record that exist in both collections.

Is that what you wanted?  It is not clear from your question if you want to find records that exist in  collection1 and *multiple times* in collection2.  If that is what you want, you will need to dig deeper.

Comment: Yes ..your second statement is what i want..

Answer (score 0):

Methods like `Intersect()` etc. should help.

Don't use collections, use `Set<T>` classes (or convert your collections to sets).
Then you can call methods like `Intersect()`, it is just faster (but you trade of memory for speed)

Comment: intersect will return me common records. I want t to find records that exist in collection1 and multiple times in collection2

Comment: What you can do is to GroupBy the collection, the filter where there is more than one in a group (so the "multiple times" criteria is satisfied) and then use Intersect or Except, depending on what you want.